# Content que carrega outras páginas sem atualizar a masterpage

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, ajax

Olá, tudo bem? Gostaria de fazer um menu lateral com o carregamento de uma página ao lado, só que ao selecionar um item do menu, eu não quero que seja carregada 100% da página e sim apenas aquela parte em especifico. Eu já tentei criar uma masterpage chamando-a na página de conteúdo, porém não tenho o resulto que espero.Segue exemplo na imagem:

```
<?php include 'masterpage.php' ?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como mostra a imagem, eu gostaria de carregar apenas a parte que tá em branco, que seria meu conteúdo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Com ajax tu faz exatamente isso, pode disparar uma função com jquery ao clicar em um dado elemento do menu, pode ler sobre ajax em:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
mas vamos exemplificar:
seu item do menu é:

```
  <li id="pag1">Pag1</li>
```

agora na parte do jquery tu ira fazer uma função para monitorar quando for clicado

```
$("#pag1").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
type :"POST",
 async: false,
 url: paginadeconteudo.php",
}).done(function(data){
    $("#conteudo").html(data);  // isso fara com que tudo que tu 
   // colocou para mostrar em paginadeconteudo será exibido da div 
  //  conteúdo que seria o teu meio.
});

}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! Vou da estudar sobre.